# lighttpd mod_rewrite url

Tags: url, url-rewriting, lighttpd

My htaccess sample:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^login$ index.php
ErrorDocument 500 /login
```

When i tried with url.rewrite:

```
url.rewrite = ("^login$" => "index.php")
```

It failed. Anything missing here?

lighttpd.conf:

```
server.modules = (
"mod_access",
"mod_alias",
"mod_compress",
"mod_redirect",
   "mod_rewrite",
    "mod_scgi",
)

url.access-deny             = ( "~", ".inc" )
url.rewrite-once = ( "^login$" => "index.php" )

static-file.exclude-extensions = ( ".php", ".pl", ".fcgi" )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this : `url.rewrite-once = ( "^login$" => "index.php" )`

Comment: @Mezzan did you restart lighty? 'cause the rewrite seems ok to me.

Comment: @j0k i'm having problem restarting lighty: Cannot load plugin mod_fastcgi more than once, please fix your config (we may not accept such configs in future releases. also Cannot load plugin mod_auth

Comment: So these errors are not related to the url-rewrite. Could you paste your `lighttpd.conf`?

Comment: i have fixed the mod errors however the url.rewrite still not working. I'm pasting the conf at original post.